String arguments shifting between unrelated functions in Multi-Threaded C Program on RTEMS
I'm developing a multi-threaded C program to run on BeagleBone Black using RTEMS 6. I've encountered an issue where string arguments for a function are being used in the wrong position, leading to unexpected behavior.
For example, a string intended as an argument for function A ends up being passed to function B. The code logic appears correct, and I'm passing the right strings, but the program still uses an incorrect string. The issue does not appear frequently since I only encounter once out of multiple times.
EDIT 2
About the platform I am using
Hardware: Beaglebone Black
OS: RTEMS 6 https://www.rtems.org/
Platform: https://github.com/nasa/cFS
Module: This module will be run-time loaded into the memory and is the first module that I encounter string shifting. There are other modules as well that encounter the same problem (not using OS_MutSemCreate). But due to the similarity and confidentiality, I cannot put it here.
I created a minimal reproducible example below. This example actually does not encounter string shifting like the last time. But I did realy find something interesting, which I will describe below.
#include "minimal_lib.h"
#include "minimal_lib_version.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef enum
{
    CAMERA,
    SENSOR
} DeviceType;

typedef enum
{
    DEV_0,
    DEV_1,
    DEV_2,
    DEV_3,
    DEV_4,
    DEV_5,
    DEV_6,
    DEV_7,
    DEV_8,
    DEV_9,
    DEV_10,
    DEV_11,
    DEV_12,
    DEV_13,
    DEV_14,
    DEV_15,
    DEV_16,
    DEV_17,
    DEV_18,
    DEV_19,
    DEV_20,
    DEV_21,
    DEV_22,
    DEV_23,
    DEV_24,
    DEV_25,
    DEV_26,
    DEV_27,
    DEV_28,
    DEV_29,
    DEV_30
} DeviceId;

typedef struct
{
    uint32 mutex;
} MutexHandler_t;

/* Camera type that has image_str */
typedef struct
{
    MutexHandler_t mutex;
    DeviceId       Id;
    char           image_str[20];
} Camera_t;

Camera_t cameraHandler[2]  = {{.Id = DEV_0}, {.Id = DEV_1}};

/* Sensor does not contain image_str */
typedef struct
{
    MutexHandler_t mutex;
    DeviceId       Id;
} Sensor_t;

Sensor_t sensorHandler[29] = {{.Id = DEV_2},  {.Id = DEV_3},  {.Id = DEV_4},  {.Id = DEV_5},  {.Id = DEV_6},
                              {.Id = DEV_7},  {.Id = DEV_8},  {.Id = DEV_9},  {.Id = DEV_10}, {.Id = DEV_11},
                              {.Id = DEV_12}, {.Id = DEV_13}, {.Id = DEV_14}, {.Id = DEV_15}, {.Id = DEV_16},
                              {.Id = DEV_17}, {.Id = DEV_18}, {.Id = DEV_19}, {.Id = DEV_20}, {.Id = DEV_21},
                              {.Id = DEV_22}, {.Id = DEV_23}, {.Id = DEV_24}, {.Id = DEV_25}, {.Id = DEV_26},
                              {.Id = DEV_27}, {.Id = DEV_28}, {.Id = DEV_29}, {.Id = DEV_30}};

/**
 * @brief This function will return the correct string.
 */
void getDeviceString(int32 id, char *deviceID)
{
    switch (id)
    {
        case DEV_0:
            CFE_PSP_MemCpy(deviceID, "DEV_0", strlen("DEV_0")); // The same as memcpy
            deviceID[strlen("DEV_0")] = '\0';
            break;
        case DEV_1:
            CFE_PSP_MemCpy(deviceID, "DEV_1", strlen("DEV_1")); // The same as memcpy
            deviceID[strlen("DEV_1")] = '\0';
            break;
        case DEV_2:
            CFE_PSP_MemCpy(deviceID, "DEV_2", strlen("DEV_2")); // The same as memcpy
            deviceID[strlen("DEV_2")] = '\0';
            break;
        case DEV_3:
            CFE_PSP_MemCpy(deviceID, "DEV_3", strlen("DEV_3")); // The same as memcpy
            deviceID[strlen("DEV_3")] = '\0';
            break;
        case DEV_4:
            CFE_PSP_MemCpy(deviceID, "DEV_4", strlen("DEV_4")); // The same as memcpy
            deviceID[strlen("DEV_4")] = '\0';
            break;
        case DEV_5:
            CFE_PSP_MemCpy(deviceID, "DEV_5", strlen("DEV_5")); // The same as memcpy
            deviceID[strlen("DEV_5")] = '\0';
            break;
        case DEV_6:
            CFE_PSP_MemCpy(deviceID, "DEV_6", strlen("DEV_6")); // The same as memcpy
            deviceID[strlen("DEV_6")] = '\0';
            break;
        case DEV_7:
            CFE_PSP_MemCpy(deviceID, "DEV_7", strlen("DEV_7")); // The same as memcpy
            deviceID[strlen("DEV_7")] = '\0';
            break;
        case DEV_8:
            CFE_PSP_MemCpy(deviceID, "DEV_8", strlen("DEV_8")); // The same as memcpy
            deviceID[strlen("DEV_8")] = '\0';
            break;
        case DEV_9:
            CFE_PSP_MemCpy(deviceID, "DEV_9", strlen("DEV_9")); // The same as memcpy
            deviceID[strlen("DEV_9")] = '\0';
            break;
        case DEV_10:
            CFE_PSP_MemCpy(deviceID, "DEV_10", strlen("DEV_10")); // The same as memcpy
            deviceID[strlen("DEV_10")] = '\0';
            break;
        case DEV_11:
            CFE_PSP_MemCpy(deviceID, "DEV_11", strlen("DEV_11")); // The same as memcpy
            deviceID[strlen("DEV_11")] = '\0';
            break;
        case DEV_12:
            CFE_PSP_MemCpy(deviceID, "DEV_12", strlen("DEV_12")); // The same as memcpy
            deviceID[strlen("DEV_12")] = '\0';
            break;
        case DEV_13:
            CFE_PSP_MemCpy(deviceID, "DEV_13", strlen("DEV_13")); // The same as memcpy
            deviceID[strlen("DEV_13")] = '\0';
            break;
        case DEV_14:
            CFE_PSP_MemCpy(deviceID, "DEV_14", strlen("DEV_14")); // The same as memcpy
            deviceID[strlen("DEV_14")] = '\0';
            break;
        case DEV_15:
            CFE_PSP_MemCpy(deviceID, "DEV_15", strlen("DEV_15")); // The same as memcpy
            deviceID[strlen("DEV_15")] = '\0';
            break;
        case DEV_16:
            CFE_PSP_MemCpy(deviceID, "DEV_16", strlen("DEV_16")); // The same as memcpy
            deviceID[strlen("DEV_16")] = '\0';
            break;
        case DEV_17:
            CFE_PSP_MemCpy(deviceID, "DEV_17", strlen("DEV_17")); // The same as memcpy
            deviceID[strlen("DEV_17")] = '\0';
            break;
        case DEV_18:
            CFE_PSP_MemCpy(deviceID, "DEV_18", strlen("DEV_18")); // The same as memcpy
            deviceID[strlen("DEV_18")] = '\0';
            break;
        case DEV_19:
            CFE_PSP_MemCpy(deviceID, "DEV_19", strlen("DEV_19")); // The same as memcpy
            deviceID[strlen("DEV_19")] = '\0';
            break;
        case DEV_20:
            CFE_PSP_MemCpy(deviceID, "DEV_20", strlen("DEV_20")); // The same as memcpy
            deviceID[strlen("DEV_20")] = '\0';
            break;
        case DEV_21:
            CFE_PSP_MemCpy(deviceID, "DEV_21", strlen("DEV_21")); // The same as memcpy
            deviceID[strlen("DEV_21")] = '\0';
            break;
        case DEV_22:
            CFE_PSP_MemCpy(deviceID, "DEV_22", strlen("DEV_22")); // The same as memcpy
            deviceID[strlen("DEV_22")] = '\0';
            break;
        case DEV_23:
            CFE_PSP_MemCpy(deviceID, "DEV_23", strlen("DEV_23")); // The same as memcpy
            deviceID[strlen("DEV_23")] = '\0';
            break;
        case DEV_24:
            CFE_PSP_MemCpy(deviceID, "DEV_24", strlen("DEV_24")); // The same as memcpy
            deviceID[strlen("DEV_24")] = '\0';
            break;
        case DEV_25:
            CFE_PSP_MemCpy(deviceID, "DEV_25", strlen("DEV_25")); // The same as memcpy
            deviceID[strlen("DEV_25")] = '\0';
            break;
        case DEV_26:
            CFE_PSP_MemCpy(deviceID, "DEV_26", strlen("DEV_26")); // The same as memcpy
            deviceID[strlen("DEV_26")] = '\0';
            break;
        case DEV_27:
            CFE_PSP_MemCpy(deviceID, "DEV_27", strlen("DEV_27")); // The same as memcpy
            deviceID[strlen("DEV_27")] = '\0';
            break;
        case DEV_28:
            CFE_PSP_MemCpy(deviceID, "DEV_28", strlen("DEV_28")); // The same as memcpy
            deviceID[strlen("DEV_28")] = '\0';
            break;
        case DEV_29:
            CFE_PSP_MemCpy(deviceID, "DEV_29", strlen("DEV_29")); // The same as memcpy
            deviceID[strlen("DEV_29")] = '\0';
            break;
        case DEV_30:
            CFE_PSP_MemCpy(deviceID, "DEV_30", strlen("DEV_30")); // The same as memcpy
            deviceID[strlen("DEV_30")] = '\0';
            break;
        default:
            deviceID[0] = '\0';
            return;
    }
}

/**********************************************************************************
 * Mutex API
**********************************************************************************/

/**
 * @brief Initialize the mutex. This also works on Linux.
 */
int32 mutexInitialize(MutexHandler_t *hwMutex, DeviceId ID)
{
    int32 Status = OS_SUCCESS;
    char  mutex_name[OS_MAX_API_NAME];
    char  deviceID[OS_MAX_API_NAME];

    CFE_PSP_MemSet(deviceID, 0, OS_MAX_API_NAME); // The same as memset
    getDeviceString(ID, deviceID);

    if (deviceID == NULL)
    {
        return OS_ERROR;
    }

    CFE_PSP_MemSet(mutex_name, 0, OS_MAX_API_NAME);         // The same as memset
    CFE_PSP_MemCpy(mutex_name, deviceID, strlen(deviceID)); // The same as memcpy
    mutex_name[strlen(deviceID)] = '\0';

    Status = OS_MutSemCreate(&hwMutex->mutex, mutex_name, 0);

    /**
     * Printing the mutex_name for observation
     */
    printf("OS_MutSemCreate(%d)(%s): %d\n", ID, mutex_name, Status);

    return Status;
}

int32 CameraInitialize(DeviceId ID)
{
    if(ID < DEV_2)
        return mutexInitialize(&cameraHandler[ID].mutex, cameraHandler[ID].Id);
}

/**********************************************************************************
 * Camera API
**********************************************************************************/

// This is part of the API that this module provide, it is not being called anywhere yet.
// And the string only be used for camera type only
void generateString(char array[20])
{
    CFE_PSP_MemSet(array, 0, OS_MAX_API_NAME);
    CFE_PSP_MemCpy(array, "image_1.png", strlen("image_1.png"));
    array[strlen("image_1.png")] = '\0';
    /**
     * This is the first string that override on the mutex name
     * I tried to comment it first, then it jumps to the second string (see below)
     */
}

int32 CameraCapture(DeviceId ID)
{
    /**
     * Check for corrected ID first, it can only be DEV_0 or DEV_1 
     * Then generate the string
     */

    generateString(cameraHandler[ID].image_str);
}

/**********************************************************************************
 * Sensor API
**********************************************************************************/

int32 SensorInitialize(DeviceId ID)
{
    return mutexInitialize(&sensorHandler[ID - DEV_2].mutex, sensorHandler[ID - DEV_2].Id);
}

int32 SensorCapture(DeviceId ID)
{
    return OS_SUCCESS;
}

/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
/*                                                                 */
/* Library Initialization Routine                                  */
/* cFE requires that a library have an initialization routine      */
/*                                                                 */
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
int32 MINIMAL_LibInit(void)
{
    int32 Status = MINIMAL_Function();
    if(Status != OS_SUCCESS)
    {
        return OS_ERROR;
    }

    OS_printf("MLib Initialized.  Version %d.%d.%d.%d\n", MINIMAL_LIB_MAJOR_VERSION, MINIMAL_LIB_MINOR_VERSION,
              MINIMAL_LIB_REVISION, MINIMAL_LIB_MISSION_REV);

    return CFE_SUCCESS;

} /* End MINIMAL_LibInit */

/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
/*                                                                 */
/* Minimal Lib function                                             */
/*                                                                 */
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
int32 MINIMAL_Function(void)
{
    int32 Status;
    Status = CameraInitialize(DEV_0);
    Status = CameraInitialize(DEV_1);

    for(DeviceId i = DEV_2; i <= DEV_30; i++)
    {
        Status = SensorInitialize(i);
    }

    return (CFE_SUCCESS);

} /* End MINIMAL_Function */

In this example, I put all of the functions into a single .c file.
From that, I tried break them into smaller files like this:
minimal_example tree
Only then I encounter the same error. Here is the result from console:
OS_MutSemCreate(0)(image): 0 // This is from *generateString*
OS_MutSemCreate(1)(DEV_1): 0
OS_MutSemCreate(2)(DEV_2): 0
...

I attached the CMakeLists file for the version I got the error just in case:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6.4)
project(CFE_MINIMAL_LIB C)

include_directories(fsw/public_inc)
include_directories(fsw/hardware/inc)
include_directories(fsw/mutex/inc)

# The shared OSAL and cFE include directories should always be used
# Note that this intentionally does NOT include PSP-specific includes, just the generic
include_directories(${CFECORE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/inc)
include_directories(${CFEPSP_SOURCE_DIR}/fsw/inc)

aux_source_directory(fsw/src LIB_SRC_FILES)
aux_source_directory(fsw/hardware/src LIB_SRC_FILES)
aux_source_directory(fsw/mutex/src LIB_SRC_FILES)

# Create the app module
add_cfe_app(minimal_lib ${LIB_SRC_FILES})

IF(CFE_SYSTEM_PSPNAME STREQUAL "pc-linux")
    target_link_libraries(minimal_lib m)
ELSEIF(CFE_SYSTEM_PSPNAME STREQUAL "bbb-rtems")
    target_link_libraries(minimal_lib ${RTEMS_MATH_OBJECT_PATH})
ENDIF()

Has anyone experienced a similar issue or have suggestions on how to diagnose and fix this problem? If you need any information, please let me know.
Thank you in advance.

I added a snippet of get_device_id_string since it is quite long.

I'm not familiar with [tag:rtems] so It's not easy for me to see where your threading comes in here. I am guessing that you have a race condition, but without a [mre] it'll be hard to tell.

"for a specific value (5, sometime it changes) that it returns the wrong string". Can you tell us more? Im my opinion, the problem is elesewhere in "get_device_id_string", and  your code snippet omits exactly the problematic part.

Note that the if (deviceID == NULL) block in HW_ADMIN_InitMutex is redundant because deviceID is an array, not a pointer.

What does OS_MutSemCreate do with the pointer to the mutex name in the second parameter? Does it copy the mutex name somewhere, or does it just store the pointer? This is an important thing to know because the pointer to the first element of mutex_name passed in the second argument of the call to OS_MutSemCreate in HW_ADMIN_InitMutex will become invalid once the call to HW_ADMIN_InitMutex has returned to its caller.

Note that the two lines CFE_PSP_MemCpy(array, "image_1.png", strlen("image_1.png")); array[strlen("image_1.png")] = '\0'; could be changed to the single line CFE_PSP_MemCpy(array, "image_1.png", 1 + strlen("image_1.png")); because the anonymous array object containing the string literal value will be null-terminated by the compiler. If CFE_PSP_StrCpy exists and does the same thing as strcpy, you could call that instead.

Looking at the source for OSAL, it looks like the name passed to OS_MutSemCreate gets copied into the created object (by the OS_OBJECT_INIT macro defined in "src/os/shared/inc/shared/inc/os-shared-idmap.h"), so the potential problem I mentioned in the comment above is not actually a problem.

I add a minimal example for clarification and I will try to reproduce it as soon as possible.

@GiuseppeGuerrini In the last several days, I made some modification and the value causing the error change. But at the moment it remains at 5. About the get string function, I ran it on linux before without any trouble, so I don't know why would it fails when changing the platform.

@IanAbbott I add some extra information about the platform. I hope it helps.

You should always mentally replace "I ran it before without any trouble" with "I ran it before and didn't notice any symptoms of trouble", since undefined behavior is infamous for seeming to do the right thing under certain circumstances but going badly wrong in others.
